# Image upload fails

Tags: 7, files

I am running drupal 7 on Arch Linux with PHP 5.3, nginx, and php-fpm. I can't upload any image, and I get the following error:

> An unrecoverable error occurred. The uploaded file likely exceeded the maximum file size

php.ini, nginx.conf, and my.conf all have their respective directives set to allow 1GB. I get this error even if I try to upload 1KB.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: That error message should have more after it, and report what it thinks the max filesize is (the min of post_max_size and upload_max_filesize).

Answer (score 3):

It was the nginx progress module. I disabled that, and everything now works.